# A space curve with the circle projection

Tags: curves, vector-fields

Consider a space curve which its projection onto $xy$-plane is a circle. Is it true necessarily for that curve $x = R\sin t$ and $y = R\cos t$? It seems reasonable but I don't whether there is a proof for it.One obvious example is the helix. I think it is related to the definition of projection.

Comment: No of course not.  Try $x = R \sin (f(t))$ and $y = R \cos (f(t))$, for starters.  For an infinite number of $f$s.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks, So if we know the projection of the curve, we can't conclude anything about the curve right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the curve projects to a circle centered at the origin (possibly partially, but with no point elsewhere), then yes, for any point of the curve there are $r$ and $t$ such that

$$x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t.$$

Comment: How we can prove that?

Comment: @S.H.W: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\arctan y/x$ are always defined. Actually, the fact that the points come from the projection of a 3D curve is completely irrelevant.

Comment: What do you think about DavidG.Stork's comment?

Comment: @S.H.W: it is true (though poorly phrased).

Comment: So we can't conclude $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$ in the general case right?

Comment: @S.H.W: I don't think you understood my answer.

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain more please?

Comment: @S.H.W: I say *there exist* $r$ and $t$.

Comment: So it is possible that $r$ and $t$ be different for the distinct points of the curve?

Comment: @S.H.W: $r$ is constant, not $t$.